# Running xDebug and NPM at the same time?

Tags: debug, scripts

I'm wondering whether the following is possible.
WordPress scripts is set up in the theme folder.
xDebug is set up in the WP installation folder.

So for each, a separate folder should be opened in VS code.

Is it possible somehow to run the two at the same time, so I can view all objects etc available while developing a theme?

Or is this something that is not possible.

Thanks!

Comment: this sounds more like a VSCode question, xdebug is a server level thing not a folder/application layer thing, and by npm I'm assuming you meant the node debugger/browser remote debugger? You're better asking this on Stackoverflow, this is unlikely to have anything to do with WordPress other than circumstance

Comment: XDebug is available on VSCode extension.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xdebug.php-debug

Comment: I'm running Local By Flywheel, and it has a Xdebug + Vscode extension. Thing is, It would be great to have this running while I'm creating the theme. The issue is, that the theme is using wordpress/scripts. So webpack and scss etc compiling. To have Wordpress compile my code, I need to have the theme's folder open. To have xdebug open, I have to have the root directory open. So for example, if I'm working on a part of the page, I have to have separate folders open for debugging the php, and changing the scss. Sorry if I didn't ask this well in my initial question.